# Look minimum pair value recursively within SQL

Tags: sql, database

I have the table

```
   ID   MIN_ID
   1    1
   2    1
   3    1
   4    4
   5    1
   6    5
   7    6
   8    4
```

I need the third column FINAL_ID that will return MIN_ID if ID = MIN_ID otherwise it will look recursively within the table until it finds the row where ID = MIN_ID. The result should be

```
   ID   MIN_ID  FINAL_ID
   1    1       1
   2    1       1
   3    1       1
   4    4       4
   5    1       1
   6    5       1        // 5 have the MIN_ID of 1
   7    6       1       // 6 have the MIN_ID of 1 and 5 have the MIN_ID of 1.
   8    4       4       // 8 goes to 4, 4 goes to 4. Done.
```

The question is how could I get this result without any procedure languages just within SQL. Any DBMS example would fit (MySQL, PostgreSQL, DB2, SQL Server, Oracle)

For example the php code that does it:

```
<?php

$table = [
    ['ID' => '1', 'MIN_ID' => '1'],
    ['ID' => '2', 'MIN_ID' => '1'],
    ['ID' => '3', 'MIN_ID' => '1'],
    ['ID' => '4', 'MIN_ID' => '4'],
    ['ID' => '5', 'MIN_ID' => '1'],
    ['ID' => '6', 'MIN_ID' => '5'],
    ['ID' => '7', 'MIN_ID' => '6'],
];


for ($x = 0; $x < count($table); $x++) {
    $table[$x]['FINAL_ID'] = calculate_final_id($table, $table[$x]);
}

print_r($table);


function calculate_final_id($table, $row)
{

    if ($row['ID'] == $row['MIN_ID']) {
        return $row['ID'];
    }

    $next_row = search($table, $row['MIN_ID']);

    return calculate_final_id($table, $next_row);
}

function search($table, $id)
{
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($table); $x++) {
        if ($table[$x]['ID'] == $id) {
            return $table[$x];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer will be different depending on the dbms used.

Comment: @jarlh - the only "dialect" part of my answer is using a table variable to hold the sample data. The remainder is standard SQL. (For modern versions of the standard)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Nice. ANSI SQL is usually the way to go, but when it comes to non-core functionality it's no longer a guarantee. I suppose your query wont run on MySQL? And what about DB2?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server example. Builds on ID's order

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
    (ID int, MIN_ID int);

INSERT INTO myTable
    (ID, MIN_ID)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 4),
    (5, 1),
    (6, 5),
    (7, 6)
;
WITH rc AS (
    SELECT ID, MIN_ID as FinalId
    FROM myTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rc.ID, t.MIN_ID   
    FROM rc 
    JOIN myTable t ON rc.FinalId = t.ID AND t.ID != t.MIN_ID
)
SELECT ID, min(FinalId) FinalId
FROM rc
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Although it may be implied by the column name, this answer assumes that the correct final answer is the lowest numeric value. If the second and third rows were `(2,3)` and `(3,4)` then, according to the spec, the correct final result would have `(2,4)` whereas your query would return `(2,3)`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Exactly. This is what I was trying to say, "Builds on ID's order"

Comment: You are welcome, Be sure to check your data doesn't contain the partern @Damien_The_Unbeliever pionted out.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever maybe I should say, that the pre-calculated minimum ID is never more than the ID. The Built on ID's order decision fit for my purposes. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (SQL Server syntax for the table variable):

```
declare @t table (ID int not null, MIN_ID int not null)
insert into @t(ID,MIN_ID) values
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,1),
(4,4),
(5,1),
(6,5),
(7,6)

;With Search as (
    select
        ID,MIN_ID,MIN_ID as FINAL_ID,0 as Depth
    from @t
    union all
    select
        s.ID,s.MIN_ID,t.MIN_ID,Depth+1
    from
        Search s
            inner join
        @t t
            on
                s.FINAL_ID = t.ID
    where
        s.FINAL_ID != t.MIN_ID
), Ordered as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Depth desc) as rn
    from Search
)
select *
from Ordered
where rn = 1
```

Basically, we keep recomputing the `FINAL_ID` if we can and keep track of how deeply we've searched - then select the deepest result for each `ID` value.

Results:

```
ID          MIN_ID      FINAL_ID    Depth       rn
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
1           1           1           0           1
2           1           1           0           1
3           1           1           0           1
4           4           4           0           1
5           1           1           0           1
6           5           1           1           1
7           6           1           2           1
```

(The recursive CTE (`Search`) and the windowed function (`ROW_NUMBER`) are standard SQL that *should* work on any modern SQL database)

Comment: Thank you so much. My SQL database is not so modern and does not support that feature but I can import my table to SQL Server and calculate it there.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can gather i think you want to use a `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT ID, MIN_ID, CASE WHEN ID = MIN_ID THEN MIN_ID ELSE 1 END AS FINAL_ID
FROM yourtable
```

Output:

```
ID  MIN_ID  FINAL_ID
1   1       1
2   1       1
3   1       1
4   4       4
5   1       1
6   5       1
7   6       1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c208d8/1/0

Comment: Lack of proper sample data... This will work for the specified data, but not if things get more complicated,  _return MIN_ID if ID = MIN_ID otherwise it will look recursively within the table until it finds the row where ID = MIN_ID_.

Comment: If I add the record with ID = 8 and MIN_id = 4 (for example) that will not work. It should return 4 but will return 1.

Comment: @Восилей, add that row to your sample data!

Comment: @jarlh already done ;) You can guess the result by the function that I wrote above ;)